# eval() returns undefined code

Tags: javascript, eval

When I'm trying `eval(command)` in the console it just gives me "undefined". What I am trying to do is to put the "command" as a line. How?

```
str = ""
command = ""

if (document.checks.cb1.checked) {str += " && randomNum3 != 1"}
if (document.checks.cb2.checked) {str += " && randomNum3 != 2"}
if (document.checks.cb3.checked) {str += " && randomNum3 != 3"}
if (document.checks.cb4.checked) {str += " && randomNum3 != 4"}

command = "while (str == str" + str + ") {randomNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 5)) + 5}"
eval(command)
```

Comment: Because the code you `eval`uate does not return any value. What value do you think it should return?

Comment: Don't use `eval`, you don't need it.

Comment: Yes but it sets the "randomNum3"

Comment: How can I execute "command" in this case ??

Comment: Someone please post an answer that does the same thing without `eval`. One less `eval` in the world makes it a better place for all of us.

Comment: I mean how can I write the "command" as a line?

Comment: What are you trying to actually do here? Can you describe the process you're trying to implement and why you're trying to implement it?

Comment: the code in `command` has an error in it. If you use `console.log()` to view the contents of `command`, you'll see what the error is. This demonstrates one of the many reasons why `eval()` is such a bad idea; it can make really obvious programming errors very difficult to spot. You *really* don't want to be using `eval()` here.

Comment: @SDC: now I'm curios what error I'm not seeing in that code, after logging it...
Also, jbabey: done.

Answer (score 3):

You can code that without `eval`. This should do the trick:

```
var num = [];

if (document.checks.cb1.checked) {num.push(1)}
if (document.checks.cb2.checked) {num.push(2)}
if (document.checks.cb3.checked) {num.push(3)}
if (document.checks.cb4.checked) {num.push(4)}

while (num.indexOf(randomNum3) == -1) {
    randomNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 5)) + 5;
}
```

Assuming `str` and `randomNum3` are defined, this should return you a random number.

Comment: Nah, doesn't work, I want to place the "str" in the command like this:____________________________________________________________ while (str == str||STR||) {randomNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 5)) + 5

Comment: What do you mean with `(str == str||STR||)`? That's not valid JS.

Comment: I want to place the "str" there, the str == str is just cause of the && to fit